# 20.04LTS - audio won't go to bluetooth device while HDMI video is connected

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, video, hdmi

I have just switched from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS on my HP laptop.
Since switching to 20.04LTS, I cannot get audio on my BlueTooth devices while using the HDMI cable for video. When using the HDMI cable, both video & audio go to TV.
Without HDMI cable, audio goes to BlueTooth devices without a problem.
But I cannot get HDMI video + BlueTooth audio at the same time.
This is very frustrating as when using 18.04LTS I had been using BlueTooth earbuds + HDMI video for Zoom meetings etc.
Is this just me, or has anyone else seen this issue?